# Reading non-text files into Python

Tags: python, file

I want to read in a non text file. It has an extension **".map"** but can be opened by notepad. How should I open this file through python?

`file = open("path-to-file","r")` doesn't work for me. It returns **No such file or directory:** error.

Here's what my file looks like:

`111    +   gi|89106884|ref|AC_000091.1|    725803  TCGAGATCGACCATGTTGCCCGCCT   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   0   14:A>G
 457    +   gi|89106884|ref|AC_000091.1|    32629   CCGTGTCCACCGACTACGACACCTC   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   0   4:C>G,22:T>C
 779    +   gi|89106884|ref|AC_000091.1|    483582  GATCACCCACGCAAAGATGGGGCGA   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   0   15:A>G,18:C>G
 784    +   gi|89106884|ref|AC_000091.1|    226200  ACCGATAGTGAACCAGTACCGTGAG   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   1`

If I do the follwing:

```
file = open("D:\bowtie-0.12.7-win32\bowtie-0.12.7\output_635\results_NC_000117.fna.1.ebwt.map","rb")
```

It still gives me `No such file or directory: 'D:\x08owtie-0.12.7-win32\x08owtie-0.12.7\\output_635\results_NC_000117.fna.1.ebwt.map'` error. Is this because the file isn't binary or I don't have some permissions?

Would apppreciate help with this!

Comment: Define "doesn't work for me".  Please read the [faq] and [ask] to understand the basic information you should provide in a question.  Imaging walking into an auto repair shop and saying "My car won't run, what's wrong with it"? (and the car is nowhere to be seen)

Comment: It might be helpful if You'd upload a sample file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binary files should use a binary mode.

```
f = open("path-to-file","rb")
```

But that won't help if you don't have the appropriate permissions or don't know the format of the file itself.

**EDIT:**

Obviously you didn't bother reading the error message, or you would have noticed that the filename it is using is not the one you expected.

```
f = open("D:\\bowtie-0.12.7-win32\\bowtie-0.12.7\\output_635\\results_NC_000117.fna.1.ebwt.map","rb")
f = open(r"D:\bowtie-0.12.7-win32\bowtie-0.12.7\output_635\results_NC_000117.fna.1.ebwt.map","rb")
```

Comment: Tried this method but didn't really work. Maybe due to the fact that its not a binary file? I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

If its a non-text file you could try opening it using `binary` format. Try this -

```
with open("path-to-file", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        byte = f.read(1) # Do stuff with byte.
```

The `with` statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block.

Of course since the format is binary you need to know what you are going to do after you read. Also, here I read 1 byte at a time, you can define bigger chunk sizes too.

**UPDATE:** Maybe this is not a binary file. You might be having problems with file encoding, the characters might not be ascii or they might belong to unicode charset. Try this -

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(u'path-to-file','r','utf-8')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

If you print this out in the terminal, you might still get gibberish since the terminal might not support this charset. I would advise, go ahead & process the text assuming its properly opened.

[Source](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html)

Comment: opening the file with  the `rb` option doesn't seem to work for me :/

Answer (score 1):

You have hit upon a minor difference between Unix and Windows here.

Since you mentioned Notepad, you must be running this on Windows. In DOS/Windows land, opening a binary file requires specifying attribute 'b' for binary, as others have already indicated. Unix/Linux are a bit more relaxed about this. Omitting attribute 'b' will still open a binary file.

The same behavior is exhibited in the C library's fopen() call.

Comment: Only because there is no difference between text and binary files on *nix.